# How can i guarantee that my site won't get down with too many players accessing it?

Tags: php, node.js, game-development

i'm creating a simple browser game with online transactions, but i'm thinking... "How can i guarantee that my site won't get down with too many players accessing it?"

I'm asking because i'll pay digital influencers to do the marketing, so i suppose many people will access it...

I should contract a VPN and run backend with node.js or pure PHP will do a good job to hold the site?

Comment: Load test your server to understand how many users it can handle and then limit the number of concurrent users to that many.  Or, bump up your server hardware, load test again and limit your server to that higher number.  Once you've established load test limits, you can also profile your server to find bottlenecks and improve your code to handle more users.

Comment: Note, proper load testing of a site is a major development job to do it right so don't expect this is something you can do quickly.  To design a meaningful load test that simulates real world usage, it will take some significant coding.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Site stability has a lot of different factors. Two main points to consider:

- **If your site is static HTML and JS files**, using a CDN like Cloudflare will provide very strong protection against the site ever going down.
- **Assuming there's a heavier lift than static files** (like DB calls and server-side processing), this ultimately comes down to two factors:

  - The specs of your server (e.g. ram, CPUs)
  - The efficiency of your code

Books can be written about how hardware and code can be improved. Ultimately releasing it in the wild will show you how they handle the load. Great monitoring software (like AppOptics) can give you insights into when you're getting close to any limits and need to upgrade hardware or optimize code.

Practically speaking, if you're not expecting a giant load on day one (which, unless you have a fantastic marketing channel or a lot of followers, you likely won't have), **you should be more concerned with building something of value than optimizing it**. Optimizing comes later.

Comment: Well, the first day will have many accesses, so can't focuses only in build something of value "/ it won't be online html + js... it'll have login/signin, top 100 highscores, etc

Comment: Ty man <3 help me a lot

Comment: @Antharaz - The first day should be a beta test period where you can measure and understand how your system runs under load.  First day should not be some big launch where you're expecting thousands of users.  No software developer is good enough to get everything right ahead of time without good testing under load.